# Is this an error in my code, or am I using arrays wrong

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm not sure why this code has an error, but it as a "bad execution error" on the line right outside of the class(the last line). This code was from more code that I copypasted onto another document, and I still got this error. I also tried using a let statement and making a function inside the class, and I still got the error. When I ran it, I also never got any error message in my console. Could this just a problem with my Xcode? If not, what am I doing wrong here?

BTW I am trying to use a 3dimentional array and I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly

```
class modelParameters {
//      w1_1
//weight^^ ^node#
//       ^layer#

//First layer
var w1_1: [Double] = []
var w1_2: [Double] = []
var w1_3: [Double] = []
var w1: [[Double]] = [mp.w1_1, mp.w1_2, mp.w1_3]

//Second layer
var w2_1: [Double] = []
var w2_2: [Double] = []
var w2_3: [Double] = []
var w2: [[Double]] = [mp.w2_1, mp.w2_2, mp.w2_3]

var ws: [[[Double]]] = [mp.w1, mp.w2]

}
var mp = modelParameters()
```

Comment: That error is terrible, but trying to access `mp` inside of `modelParameters` is some kind of ouroboros problem. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be trying to define `w1` in terms of `w1_1` and its peers. That's generally done with a computed property. There's no `mp` value at the point that ModelParameters accesses it in your code.

```
class ModelParameters {
    //      w1_1
    //weight^^ ^node#
    //       ^layer#

    //First layer
    var w1_1: [Double] = []
    var w1_2: [Double] = []
    var w1_3: [Double] = []
    var w1: [[Double]] { [w1_1, w1_2, w1_3] } // Return a value; don't assign it

    //Second layer
    var w2_1: [Double] = []
    var w2_2: [Double] = []
    var w2_3: [Double] = []
    var w2: [[Double]] { [w2_1, w2_2, w2_3] } // Also here

    var ws: [[[Double]]] { [w1, w2] } // And here

}
var mp = ModelParameters()
```